# continuity of a function from the plane to the line

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be given as

$$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{ \sin x - \sin y }{x-y}, & \text{if }\text{ $x \neq y $} \\
\cos x, & \text{if } x \text{ $=y$}
\end{cases}
$$

My claim is that the function is discontinuous along the diagonal. But how can I show this?

Comment: Try fixing $x$ and letting $y\to x$, then the other way round, fixing $y$ and letting $x\to y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your function as $$f(x,y)=\frac{ \sin x - \sin y }{x-y}=\frac{2 \sin \left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)}{x-y}$$ from which it is easy to see what happens along the diagonal (or close to it).

Comment: can you explain a little bit more? I dont see how this helps...

Comment: @Learner. Use the fact that $\frac{\sin (a)}{a}\to 1$ when $a$ is small and replace $a$ by $\frac{x-y}{2}$